# Adding a filter to my posts

Tags: functions, excerpt

Hello guys I would like to append a link to the end of the content within my post. I currently have this in my functions.php file:

```
function ifcj_comment_link() {
global $post;
return ' <a href="'. get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Israel In The News Audio Link', true) . '">' . __( '<div id="audio-player">Testing</div>', 'ifcj' ) . '</a> ';
}

function ifcj_custom_excerpt_more( $output ) {
if ( has_excerpt() || in_category( _x('israel-in-the-news', 'israel-in-the-news category slug', 'ifcj') ) &&! is_attachment() ) {
    $output .= ifcj_comment_link();
}
return $output;
}
add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'ifcj_custom_excerpt_more' );
```

It displays just fine in my categories feed page: http://stage.standforisrael.org/category/israel-in-the-news/feed

But that particular link is not showing up on the archive.php page.

Am I missing something here?

Thanks

Comment: Don't forget to use esc_attr/esc_url on that href

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The excerpt must be used by the Theme.** I don't think it is. Use **'the_content' filter** to append to the post. Excerpts are usually used in feeds and only by certain themes.

```
add_filter('the_content', function($content){
    if(!is_archive()) return $content;
    global $post; // This is the current output post
    ob_start();
    // Echo stuff to append to post here! (your link or whatever)
    return $content.ob_get_clean();
});
```

*PHP 5.3 Closure used. Extract function yourself aside for PHP 5.2.*

Regards.